# How to rearrange elements of array with integer character and symbols?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array in the form of

```
{1, a, D, 3, h, 2, C, Z, $, o, 5}
```

the result array should be

```
{1, 3, 2, 5, a, h, o, D, C, Z, $}
```

Where rearranged array should have numbers first , then the alphabets with lower case then the alphabets with uppercase and the special characters at last without using an another array.. how to do tat?

Thank u in advance...

```
private static void arrangeArrayInOrder(List<Character> arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            if (arr.get(i) >= '0' && arr.get(i) <= '9') {
                arr.add(arr.get(i));
                arr.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

first i tried to move all my integers to my array last and removing it from original position and tried to do the same with remaining conditions.. but stuck here itself couldn't proceed further.

Comment: Any attempts so far?

Comment: `Thank u in advance` ... Stack Overflow is not a free short order code writing service, like McDonald's (which however serves fries, not code).  If you want help, you will have to show us some code you have fried (sorry...tried).

Comment: Sry for that i have added the code i have tried pls take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made my logic and it works like this:

- First calculate how many `numbers, small, capitals and special` characters are there.
- Set the starting index of each type.
- Start `For-loop` and start inserting them at their right place.

Working Code:

```
public class stackLong
{
    static char[] array = {'1', 'a', 'B', '2', 'h', '3', 'C', 'Z', '$', 'o', '5'};
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int number=0,small=0,capital=0,special=0;
        //calculates the total number of characters of each type
        for(int i =0; i<array.length;i++)
        {
            if (array[i]>=65 && array[i]<=90)  // capital
                capital++;
            else if (array[i]>=97 && array[i]<=122) //small
                small++;
            else if (array[i]>=48 && array[i]<=57)  // number 
                number++;
            else if ((array[i]>0 && array[i]<=47)||(array[i]>=58 && array[i]<=64)|| (array[i]>=91 && array[i]<=96)||(array[i]>=123 && array[i]<=127))
                special++;
        }

        // sets their starting index
        int smallIndex = number;
        int capitalIndex = small + smallIndex;
        int specialIndex = capitalIndex + capital;
        number = 0;

        for(int i =0; i<array.length;i++)
        {
            if (array[i]>=48 && array[i]<=57)  // number
            {
                swap(i,number);
                number++;
            }
        }

        for(int i =smallIndex; i<array.length;i++)
        {
            if (array[i]>=97 && array[i]<=122) //small
            {
                swap(i,smallIndex);
                smallIndex++;
            }
        }

        for(int i =capitalIndex; i<array.length;i++)
        {
            if (array[i]>=65 && array[i]<=90)  // capital
            {
                swap(i,capitalIndex);
                capitalIndex++;
            }
        }

        for(int i =specialIndex; i<array.length;i++)  // special
        {
            if ((array[i]>0 && array[i]<=47)||(array[i]>=58 && array[i]<=64)|| (array[i]>=91 && array[i]<=96)||(array[i]>=123 && array[i]<=127))
            {
                swap(i,specialIndex);
                specialIndex++;
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("\n");
        for(int j =0; j<array.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.printf(array[j] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void swap(int frst, int scnd)
    {
        char temp = array[frst];
        array[frst] = array[scnd];
        array[scnd] = temp;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** There are several ways to do this, this may seem a bit naive but during interview they just want to know whether you are on a right track to find the solution of just beating about the bush.

Comment: You understood the logic ? If yes, then i am glad to help. If you find any answer that helps, you can always upvote it :)